# Divergence Theorem for 1D

Tags: gaussian-integral, divergence-theorem

As all of us know, in divergence theorem we have **This:**

[image]

this means instead of integrating a divergence of a vector over a volume, you can integrate that vector over the surface.

But I'm wondering what can we do with **This:**

[image]

I'm looking for it's concept and formula.

**EDIT:**
in other words I want to know how we use divergence theorem when we have only one partial derivative for 3D vector and what is its intuition.

Comment: 1D version of divergence formula is $\int_a^b f'(x) dx = f(b)-f(a)$.

Comment: @IvanKaznacheyeu Thank you. I know it and I've also edited my Q.

Comment: As to your question: you can split volume into infinitesimal cylinders with axes parallel to $x$-axis. Then every integral is taken as 1D using Newton-Leibniz formula. If volume is limited by surfaces $x=x_1(y,z)$ and $x=x_2(y,z)>x_1(y,z)$, then integral is equal $\iint_{yz\, domain} (F(x_2,y,z)-F(x_1,y,z))\, dy\,dz$

Comment: @IvanKaznacheyeu Thank you. Please correct me if I'm wrong. does this mean all the things we have to do is to divide our external surface of control volume to small patches and calculate surface integral for each patch and project the answer to x direction ( inner product of patch normal and x direction normal vector) ?

Comment: Yes, you're right. It could be considered as particular case of divergence theorem. Consider $\vec{F}=(f_x(x,y,z),0,0)$ then divergence ${\rm div}\, \vec{F}=\frac{\partial f_x}{\partial x}$. Then using divergence theorem gives $\iiint \frac{\partial f_x}{\partial x}\, dV = \oint f_x (\vec{i}\cdot \vec{n})\, dS$. $f_x$ is dumb function here, we can take $f_x=\vec{F} = f_x i + f_y j + f_z k$ and obtain  $\iiint \frac{\partial \vec{F}}{\partial x}\, dV = \oint \vec{F} (\vec{i}\cdot \vec{n})\, dS$

Comment: Thank you again. I think it's good idea to add this conversation as an answer to this post so I can select it and close this post. have a good time :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Consider $\vec{A}=(f_x(x,y,z),0,0)$ then divergence $${\rm div}\,\vec{A} =\frac{\partial f_x}{\partial x}$$

Then using divergence theorem gives $$\iiint \frac{\partial f_x}{\partial x}\, dV=\oint f_x (\vec{i}\cdot \vec{n}) dS$$

$f_x$ is dumb function here, we can take $f_x=\vec{F}=f_x \vec{i}+f_y \vec{j}+f_z \vec{k}$ and obtain $$\iiint \frac{\partial \vec{F}}{\partial x}\,dV=\oint \vec{F} (\vec{i}\cdot \vec{n}) \, dS$$